# A Riemannian metric on the plane such that the intersection of every two discs is a disc, again

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry, hilbert-spaces, metric-spaces

Is there a Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (or a $2$ dimensional manifold) such that the intersection of every two open discs is an open disc, again?

As linear version of this question we ask:

> Is there a Hilbert space $H$ or a Banach space $X$ for which the following property is true:

The intersection of every two discs is either empty or an open disc?

Comment: It seems unlikely because very small disks are approximately Euclidean, as rescaling to ``zoom in'' makes the curvature small.

Comment: This sounds more like something nonarchimedean...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Perhaps on $^*\mathbb{R}^2$ for an appropriately large nonstandard model of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @AlecRhea I rather had in mind something like $p$-adics

Comment: A better question to ask is if there is such a metric compatible with the usual topology in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @fedja I assume that by metric you mean a metric not necessarily coming from a Riemannian metric.

Comment: @AliTaghavi Yes, any distance function.

Comment: @fedja So $|\;\;|_\infty$ gives the required metric.

Comment: @BenMcKay may you ellaborate your comment.

Comment: @AliTaghavi Nope, the intersection of 2 squares may be a rectangle.

Comment: @fedja Yes. You are write. I was incorrect.